# Add legend to pgf plot results in \end{axis} error

Tags: tikz-pgf, legend, matlab2tikz

I exported a Matlab figure to tikz, using matlab2tikz. It is a simple plot of some lines and I need to label them. matlab2tikz did not add the legend entries automatically for the first time, so I copy/pasted the legend command from another pgf plot. It was also the first time I used it in Matlab2014. This is just FYI, but probably unrelated to the pgf problem.

Below I added the tikz/pgf code. It compiles if I comment the legend entries, but when I uncomment them I get the following error:

```
Missing } inserted \end{axis}
```

It refers to the line of \end{axis}, and a bunch of other error messages follow.

Here's the code:

```
% This file was created by matlab2tikz v0.4.4 running on MATLAB 8.4.
% Copyright (c) 2008--2013, Nico Schlömer <nico.schloemer@gmail.com>
% All rights reserved.
% 
% The latest updates can be retrieved from
%   http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz
% where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
% 
%
% defining custom colors

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\newlength\figurewidth
\setlength{\figurewidth}{\textwidth}

\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0,0.447,0.741}%
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.85,0.325,0.098}%
\definecolor{mycolor3}{rgb}{0.929,0.694,0.125}%
\definecolor{mycolor4}{rgb}{0.494,0.184,0.556}%
\definecolor{mycolor5}{rgb}{0.466,0.674,0.188}%
%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=\figurewidth,
height=0.535665322580645\figurewidth,
unbounded coords=jump,
scale only axis,
every outer x axis line/.append style={darkgray!60!black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{darkgray!60!black}},
xmin=-10,
xmax=10,
xlabel={Parameter},
every outer y axis line/.append style={darkgray!60!black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{darkgray!60!black}},
ymode=log,
ymin=1e-06,
ymax=1000,
yminorticks=true,
ylabel={Error},
axis x line    *=bottom,
axis y line    *=left,
legend style={draw=darkgray!60!black,fill=white,legend cell align=left}
]
\addplot [
color=mycolor1,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
-10 0.257539245299513\\
10 0.278411090059315\\
};
\addlegendentry{Case 1};

\addplot [
color=mycolor2,
dashed,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
-10 0.0371047553354069\\
10 0.0338867959948958\\
};
\addlegendentry{Case 2};

\addplot [
color=mycolor3,
dotted,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
-10 0.0109546932939792\\
10 0.00673477512625754\\
};
\addlegendentry{Case 3};

\addplot [
color=mycolor4,
dash pattern=on 1pt off 3pt on 3pt off 3pt,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
-10 0.0010526474053356\\
10 0.000764939997185852\\
};
\addlegendentry{Case 4};

\addplot [
color=mycolor5,
solid,
mark=+,
mark options={solid},
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
-10 0.000686338275055355\\
10 0.000758083080815557\\
};
\addlegendentry{Case 5};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Thanks for any useful insights ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding my comment to an answer.

The problem is in the use of `forget plot`.
Due to the fact `pgfplots` shall forget each plot, but on the other hand defining a legend entry for each plot, `pgfplots` doesn't know what to do.
To solve the problem two possibilities are given, based on the desired result.

1. Remove all `\addlegendentry` from the different plots, so no legend will be plotted.
2. Remove -at least one- `forget plot` to plot the legend.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for my was:

- Using `forget plot` option for entries that I don't want to see and `\addlegendentry` for entries that I want to see.
- Remove all NAN points.

If I did not do this last step, the error kept appearing